# Network `Disconnect` option grayed out after using `sudo netplan apply` (Xubuntu 20.04)

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, network-manager

I was following [this tutorial](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-on-ubuntu-20-04/) to setup static ip address on my xfce 20.04 laptop. Everything was fine until I executed `sudo netplan apply`, after which the disconnect button on the network config panel was grayed out and I was no longer able to disconnect from neither my wifi nor ethernet. I tried few things like `sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service`, `sudo rfkill unblock wifi`, and `sudo ifconfig wlp2s0 up` (yes I checked the interface name), but none worked.
After a reboot, the problem went away, but then it came back after I executed `sudo netplan apply`.
My `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yml` looks like this:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.17/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
          addresses: [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
```

For those wondering what I'm doing, I am setting up my home network with openwrt routers and it requires me to set a static ip address to be able to access them in their fail-safe mode. For that reason I am going to be changing my computer's config many times, so re-booting every time I change anything is something that I want to avoid.

Comment: You should've followed the "Configuring Static IP address on Ubuntu Desktop" instructions, not the ones for Ubuntu Server.

Comment: What a bless! After I switched to the GUI as ChanganAuto suggested, It started working like a charm! I went to the `edit connections` menu and created two network connections, one is static and the other is DHCP assigned. Now I can select either of them, and it switches up instantly without issues.  
My issue is solved, but I think I'll keep this question up in case anyone finds why the network manager menu gets grayed out in the first place.